# ASP.NET MVC: Route with optional parameter, but if supplied, must match \d+

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to write a route with a nullable int in it. It should be possible to go to both `/profile/` but also `/profile/\d+`.

```
routes.MapRoute("ProfileDetails", "profile/{userId}",
                new {controller = "Profile",
                     action = "Details",
                     userId = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new {userId = @"\d+"});
```

As you can see, I say that `userId` is optional but also that it should match the regular expression `\d+`. This does not work and I see why.

But how would I construct a route that matches just `/profile/` but also `/profile/` followed by a number?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The *simplest* way would be to just add another route without the `userId` parameter, so you have a fallback:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProfileDetails", "profile/{userId}",
                new {controller = "Profile",
                     action = "Details",
                     userId = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new {userId = @"\d+"});

routes.MapRoute("Profile", "profile",
                new {controller = "Profile",
                     action = "Details"});
```

As far as I know, the only other way you can do this would be with a custom constraint. So your route would become:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProfileDetails", "profile/{userId}",
                new {controller = "Profile",
                     action = "Details",
                     userId = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new {userId = new NullableConstraint());
```

And the custom constraint code will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class NullableConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest && parameterName == "userId")
            {
                // If the userId param is empty (weird way of checking, I know)
                if (values["userId"] == UrlParameter.Optional)
                    return true;

                // If the userId param is an int
                int id;
                if (Int32.TryParse(values["userId"].ToString(), out id))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know that `NullableConstraint` is the best name here, but that's up to you!

Comment: I made something similar to this, but slightly more generic, with a constructor that takes a regular expression to match against the provided value. Thanks!

Comment: I know I'm coming in really late here, but shouldn't that last line be return true?  Otherwise the constraint always fails if the route direction is UrlGeneration.

Comment: If the last line returned true then *anything* would match the constraint... but yes, you're right, this doesn't take into account anything other than incoming request routing. Looking at it now, I would have thought we could just remove the routeDirection part of the `if` statement altogether; I'll test tomorrow and edit if that is the case.

Comment: Maybe the assumption with the route direction code is that we trust that the parameter is going to be valid for URL generation (because the developer supplying the value).

Comment: using `int? id` will allow nullable int, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436031/asp-net-mvc-c-sharp-routing-passing-a-null-integer), hope helps.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible something changed since this question was answered but I was able to change this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    null,
    "projects/{operation}/{id}",
    "~/Projects/ProjectWizard.aspx",
    true,
    new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        operation = "new",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        id = new NullableExpressionConstraint(@"\d+")
    })
);
```

With this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    null,
    "projects/{operation}/{id}",
    "~/Projects/ProjectWizard.aspx",
    true,
    new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        operation = "new",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        id = @"\d*"
    })
);
```

Simply using the `*` instead of the `+` in the regular expression accomplished the same task. The route still fired if the parameter was not included, but if included it would only fire if the value was a valid integer. Otherwise it would fail.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET MVC 3 has solved this problem, and as [Alex Ford brought out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862336/asp-net-mvc-route-with-optional-parameter-but-if-supplied-must-match-d#comment-13558112), you can use `\d*` instead of writing a custom constraint. If your pattern is more complicated, like looking for a year with `\d{4}`, just make sure your pattern matches what you want as well as an empty string, like `(\d{4})?` or `\d{4}|^$`. Whatever makes you happy.

If you are still using ASP.NET MVC 2 and want to use [Mark Bell's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862336/asp-net-mvc-route-with-optional-parameter-but-if-supplied-must-match-d#3862677) or [NYCChris' example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862336/asp-net-mvc-route-with-optional-parameter-but-if-supplied-must-match-d#8302852), please be aware that the route will match as long as the URL parameter *contains* a match to your pattern. This means that the pattern `\d+` will match parameters like `abc123def`. To avoid this, wrap the pattern with `^(` and `)$` either when defining your routes or in the custom constraint. (If you look at [System.Web.Routing.Route.ProcessConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.processconstraint.aspx) in [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), you'll see that it does this for you when using the built in constraint. It also sets the [CultureInvariant, Compiled, and IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) options.)

Since I already wrote my own custom constraint with the default behavior mentioned above before realizing I didn't have to use it, I'll leave it here:

```cs
public class OptionalConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
  public OptionalConstraint(Regex regex)
  {
    this.Regex = regex;
  }

  public OptionalConstraint(string pattern) :
    this(new Regex("^(" + pattern + ")$",
      RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
      RegexOptions.Compiled |
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) { }

  public Regex Regex { get; set; }

  public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext,
                    Route route,
                    string parameterName,
                    RouteValueDictionary values,
                    RouteDirection routeDirection)
  {
    if(routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
    {
      object value = values[parameterName];
      if(value == UrlParameter.Optional)
        return true;
      if(this.Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

And here's an example route:

```cs
routes.MapRoute("PostsByDate",
                "{year}/{month}",
                new { controller = "Posts",
                      action = "ByDate",
                      month = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { year = @"\d{4}",
                      month = new OptionalConstraint(@"\d\d") });
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 4 also elegantly allows regular expressions that match empty strings such as `(\d{4})?`, which makes me happy.

Comment: Perhaps it's time that this answer should be marked as the correct one?

Answer (score 3):

should your regex be \d*?

Comment: With `\d*` it doesn't match at all, be it with or without `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: @DenizDogan Not sure if something changed since then but I just tested `\d*` and it accomplished the exact same thing as the `OptionalRegExConstraint`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Mark Bell for this answer, it helped me quite a bit.

I'm wondering why you hard coded the check for "userId" in the constraint?  I slightly rewrote your class like to user the `parameterName` parameter, and it seems to be working just fine.

Am I missing anything by doing it this way?

```
public class OptionalRegExConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly Regex _regEx;

    public OptionalRegExConstraint(string matchExpression=null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(matchExpression))
            _regEx = new Regex(matchExpression);
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
        {
            if (values[parameterName] == UrlParameter.Optional) return true;

            return _regEx != null && _regEx.Match(values[parameterName].ToString()).Success;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hard-coded that value only for the sake of obviousness in the example, but you're right—this approach is more flexible than mine. +1

Answer (score 0):

I needed to validate a few things with more than just a RegEx but was still getting an issue similar to this. My approach was to write a constraint wrapper for any custom route constraints I may already have:

```
public class OptionalRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public IRouteConstraint Constraint { get; set; }

    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext,
            Route route,
            string parameterName,
            RouteValueDictionary values,
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        var value = values[parameterName];

        if (value != UrlParameter.Optional)
        {
            return Constraint.Match(httpContext, route, parameterName, values, routeDirection);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in `constraints` under a route in `RouteConfig.cs`, it would look like this:

```
defaults: new {
    //... other params
    userid = UrlParameter.Optional
}
constraints: new
{
    //... other constraints
    userid = new OptionalRouteConstraint { Constraint = new UserIdConstraint() }
}
```