# ASP.NET MVC C# Routing - Passing a null integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working with MVC 3 in a web app and i'm facing a problem in routing.

I'm defining my router handler like this:

```
           routes.MapRoute(
           "Users", 
           "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Users", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

The url is: http://app.domain/Users.aspx/Details/114142/5 (example)

I'm sucefully getting the id of the user, but i can't get the page number.

The controller of users is initialized like this:

```
           public ActionResult Details(long id, int? page)
```

The page is always returning null (i need the page as a null integer).

And i defining the route wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` cannot be optional if `page` is optional. Only the **last** parameter of a route definition can be optional.

So :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Users", 
    {controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}/{page}",
    new { 
        controller = "Users",  
        action = "Details", 
        page = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

and then: `/Users.aspx/Details/114142/5` will successfully map to

```
public ActionResult Details(long id, int? page)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, that was exactly what i was looking for.
Cheers ;)

Answer (score -2):

You are using a wrong URL.
Try this:

```
http://app.domain/Users.aspx/Details/114142?page=5
```

Comment: Except that he doesn't want `/Users.aspx/Details/114142?page=5`. He wants `/Users.aspx/Details/114142/5`.

Comment: Darin is right. In fact, i was using the url with parameters. Now, i want to stop using the page=5 to pass the 5 as page.