# Not showing "Index" in URL and supplying a parameter with MVC5 routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set up some routing in one of my MVC area's.

I have a controller named `AgentGroups`. I am trying to achieve the following:

- Remove `Index` from the URL
- Supply a parameter to the Index action
- Allow all other actions to have their name in the URL and provide an optional parameter to them

So for example I'd like the following to work

```
/s/agentgroups   < (Index action)
/s/agentgroups/1 < (Index action)
/s/agentgroups/someotheraction
/s/agentgroups/someotheraction/1
```

I currently have this in my `RegisterArea` method:

```
        // s/agentgroups/action
        context.MapRoute(
            "Suppliers_actions",
            "s/{controller}/{action}/{agentgroupid}",
            new { controller = "AgentGroups", agentgroupid = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { action = "^(?!Index$).*$" }
        );

        // s/agentgroups/
        context.MapRoute(
            "Suppliers_index",
            "s/agentgroups/{agentgroupid}",
            new { controller = "AgentGroups", action = "Index", agentgroupid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This works for 3 of the 4 URL examples I gave, the one that doesn't work correctly is:

```
/s/agentgroups/1 < (Index action)
```

I'm pretty sure it thinks the `1` parameter is an action name and therefore it doesn't work..? **It does work however, if,** I pass the parameter like a regular query string ie: `?agentgroupid=1`, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

How can I change my routes to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Are `agentgroupid` in your route "Suppliers_index" integers?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Yes, the `agentgroupid` is an integer in both routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder the area routes as *Suppliers_index* is more specific (only intended for the index action) than *Suppliers_actions*. Then you will need to add a constraint for the **agentgroupid** parameter in *Suppliers_index*.

As the parameter is optional and has to match an integer, we can use the regex `\d*`, but for more complicated patterns you might need to create your own route constraint as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862677/1836935).

So your area routes may look like this: (namespaces will be different or even not needed in your case):

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Suppliers_index",
    "s/agentgroups/{agentgroupid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AgentGroups", action = "Index", agentgroupid = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { agentgroupid = @"\d*" },
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication6.Areas.AgentGroups.Controllers" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Suppliers_actions",
    "s/{controller}/{action}/{agentgroupid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AgentGroups", agentgroupid = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication6.Areas.AgentGroups.Controllers" }
);
```