# How do I configure my Route config to get a URL Pattern like localhost/Product (Controller)/List (Action)/Category (Id)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As the title says all about what I want but to be kind of specific I would like to have a URL pattern like localhost/Product/List/Category/Page but I couldn't succeed finding a solution for it. I am sure it's belong to routing and as it is difficult topic in MVC I would need your help to find a solution for it.

My route config is:

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(null, "",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Shop",

                });
            routes.MapRoute(null, "",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Product",
                    action = "list",
                    category = (string)null,
                    page = 1
                }
                );
            routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{page}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "List",
                category = (string)null,
                subcategory = (string)null
            },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List" },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
        }
    }
```

My Controller product is:

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
        private IProductsRepository repository;
        public int PageSize = 4;

        public ProductController (IProductsRepository productrepository)
        {
            this.repository = productrepository;
        }
        public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel()
            {
                Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.ProductCategory == category || p.MenSubCategory == category)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                    .Take(PageSize),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count():repository.Products.Where(e => e.ProductCategory == category).Count()
                },
                CurrentCategory = category
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult Menu(string subcategory = null )
        {
            ViewBag.SelectedCategory = subcategory;
            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.MenSubCategories
                .Select(x => x.MenSubCategory)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x);
            return PartialView(categories);
        }
}
```

I hope I get answer for this as far as I really tried but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: Remove the Home Controller code as it's irrelevant to the question. You are looking for answers for Product controller, right?

Comment: Yes Exactly. @jpgrassi

Comment: But you removed also the Product controller code. Post it again, please.

Comment: My bad sorry, updated it again. @jpgrassi

Comment: ok, what about the page parameter? Are you expecting it also from the URL?

Comment: No but when a user tries to pagination  the page number should be included in URL, Like localhost/Product/List/Category/Page1 @jpgrassi

Comment: So the page IS a parameter you will have in your url? Are you confortable with this URL: mysite/Product/List/Cars?page=10 ?

Comment: That seems to be fine but can you code it this way? mysite/Product/List/Cars/Page10 @jpgrassi

Comment: I forgot to add another necessary segment which is SubCategory mysite/product/list/category/**subcategory**/page @jpgrassi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate an URL like you want: `localhost/Product/List/Cars` you can create a custom route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductList",
    url: "Product/List/{category}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
);
```

Remember that custom routes have to come before the most general route (the one that comes with the default template).

Regarding your `page` parameter, if you are comfortable with this URL: `localhost:3288/Product/List/teste?page=10` the above already work. But if you want this: `localhost:3288/Product/List/teste/10` 10 meaning the page number, then the simplest solution would be create two different routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ProductList",
   url: "Product/List/{category}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ProductListPage",
   url: "Product/List/{category}/{page}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" , page = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Another cleaner way, is to create a custom route constraint for your optional parameter. This question has a lot of answers to that:
[ASP.NET MVC: Route with optional parameter, but if supplied, must match \d+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862336/asp-net-mvc-route-with-optional-parameter-but-if-supplied-must-match-d)

Comment: i wouldn't accept any less from you! Sucha great Answer and to the point.
One more point how can i add the subcategory to the Url?
Like mysite/Product/List/Category/SubCategory/Page

Comment: If the subcategory will be a permanent parameter and not an optional and casual one, just change the route and include it: Product/List/{category}/{subcategory}. Or to make it clear, create another route for that, this enable you to have a "backup" for all endpoints. Just note that in your List action, you will have to include this new subCategory parameter, and if it will be optional, provide a value like = null.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Got it!

Answer (score 0):

With attribute routing, you just need to decorate your action method with your specific route pattern.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
 {
     EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
     private IProductsRepository repository;
     public int PageSize = 4;

     public ProductController (IProductsRepository productrepository)
     {
          this.repository = productrepository;
     }
     [Route("Product/list/{category}/{page}")]
     public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
     {
       // to do  : Return something
     }
}
```

The above route definition will send the request like `yourSite/Product/list/phones` and `yourSite/Product/list/phones/1` to the `List` action method and the url segments for `category` and `page` will be mapped to the method parameters.

To enable attribute routing, you need to call the method `MapMvcAttributeRoutes`
method inside the `RegisterRoutes` method.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I get a 404 not found error if i type mysite/Product/List/Men

Comment: In your question i see you have other custom route definitions. Remove that. You need only the default route definition.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts I'll try your answer by tomorrow as @Jpgrassi's answer is all what i want and simpler I'll try this too obviously. It is time to sleep now :) Shyju